Conv2d with time series
I have a question about how a CONV2D layer handles time series data.
How with filters that scroll through time, our model can extract features and capture and model our target value?
Thank you in advance.

It works the same as in image-to-image NN. It recognizes patterns in the data and is trained to forecast future patterns from the past patterns. It can also support related data and attributes.
Amazon developed a relevant model.
https://kdd-milets.github.io/milets2022/papers/MILETS_2022_paper_4213.pdf

Yes, you're i see, but with images, patterns are often related to luminosity functions, which can be thought of as a function of the pixel values. This allows us to apply convolutional filters to the image data, where the filter slides over the pixels, computing a dot product at each position to generate a feature map.
However, with time series data, the concept of a luminosity function doesn't exist.
So, what can we use as a function to apply our convolutional filters to time series data?

In a time series it is a local trend of the target time series that is being highlighted. For example for daily forecast, following 5 weekdays there could be 2 weekend days that behaves differently. I don't understand why CNN would work only for luminous. It works for audio, video (4d), both are a kind of a time series.
